# How to fix issue VideoView overlay Bottom Navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-videoview, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

The `fragment` contains a `ViewPager2`, each page contains a full-screen `VideoView`. I want the `VideoView` is full screen but behind both `Status bar` and `Bottom Navigation bar` (`Status bar` and `Bottom Navigation bar` are transparent so we still see the video). 
The problem is the `VideoView` overlay the `Bottom Navigation bar`, can't see the `Bottom Bar` but still can interact with it.
How to set the `VideoView` behind the `Bottom Navigation bar` or any solution that has the same result?

[image]

**Edit**
**res/menu/bottom_nav_menu.xml**`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_white_24dp"
            android:title="@string/title_home" />
    
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_discover"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
            android:title="@string/title_discover" />
    
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
            android:title="@string/title_settings" />
    
    </menu>
```

**/res/navigation/mobile_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.android.ui.home.VideoCategoriesFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_video_category_pager" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_discover"
        android:name="com.android.ui.discover.DiscoverFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_discover"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_discovering" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
        android:name="com.android.ui.settings.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />
</navigation>
```

**video_preview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_list_video_pager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager_videos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:foreground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ListVideoPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ListVideoPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<>();
    private VideoPlayer player;
    long categoryId = -1;

    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;
        if (videos != null && videos.size() > 0) {
            fragment = new VideoPreviewFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(EXTRA_VIDEO_URI, videos.get(position).getVideoPath());
            args.putLong(EXTRA_VIDEO_ID, videos.get(position).getId());
            args.putLong(EXTRA_CATEGORY_ID, categoryId);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Math.max(videos.size(), 0);
    }

    public void addVideos(List<Video> videos) {
        this.videos.addAll(videos);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Video getItem(int position) {
        return  (videos != null && videos.size() > 0) ? videos.get(position) : null;
    }
}
```

**ListVideoFragment.java**

```
public class ListVideoFragment extends Fragment{

    public static final String EXTRA_CATEGORY_ID = "extra_category_id";

    private ListVideoPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager2 viewPager;
    private ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback pageChangeCallback;
    private static ListVideoFragment fragment;
    private VideoViewModel mVideoViewModel;
    private long categoryId = -1;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_video_pager, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            categoryId = args.getLong(EXTRA_CATEGORY_ID);
        }
        mVideoViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(VideoViewModel.class);

        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager_videos);
        if (categoryId >= 0) {
            mPagerAdapter = new ListVideoPagerAdapter(this);

            mPagerAdapter.setCategoryId(categoryId);
            try {
                List<CategoryWithVideos> data = mVideoViewModel.getVideosByCategory(categoryId);
                mPagerAdapter.addVideos(data.get(0).videos);             
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            initPager();
        }
    }

    private void initPager() {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        viewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        pageChangeCallback = new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Video video = mPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
            }
        };
        viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(pageChangeCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback(pageChangeCallback);
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

**VideoPreviewFragment.java**

```
public class VideoPreviewFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_VIDEO_URI = "extra_video_uri";
    public static final String EXTRA_VIDEO_ID = "extra_video_id";
    public static final String EXTRA_CATEGORY_ID = "extra_category_id";

    private VideoPlayer player;
    private VideoView videoView;
    private String videoURI;
    private long videoId;
    private long categoryId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            videoURI = args.getString(EXTRA_VIDEO_URI);
            videoId = args.getLong(EXTRA_VIDEO_ID);
            categoryId = args.getLong(EXTRA_CATEGORY_ID);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_view, container, false);
        videoView = view.findViewById(R.id.video_preview);
        videoView.requestFocus();       
        player = new VideoPlayer();
        initializePlayer();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        player.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        player.pause();
    }
    
    private void initializePlayer() {
        player.setVideoUri(videoURI);
        player.setVideoView(videoView);
        player.setCategoryId(categoryId);
        player.setVideoId(videoId);
        player.init();
    }
}
```

Comment: anyone can help?

Comment: Hey neo, Just for confirmation: When you say  "_The problem is the `VideoView` overlay the `BottomNavigationBar`, can't see it but still can interact with it._" , you meant that you cannot interact with the `BottomNavigationBar` ?

Comment: Can you add your layout file please?

Comment: add your xml code

Comment: Hi @Kalai sorry for my bad explanation. I mean I can't see the `BottomNavigationBar` because the `VideoView` cover it but I can still interact with it, when I touch the position where the `BottomNavigationBar` locate can still perform navigation

Comment: Is BottomNavigationBar shown when you use a different kind of View instead of VideoView (e.g. you can just use a standard View instance or FrameLayout with some background color)?

Comment: @Ridcully yes, I replaced the `VideoView` with a `FrameLayout`, the `BottomNavigationBar` showed normally

Comment: @Ridcully I edited my question, could u help?

Comment: @Kalai I edited my question, could u help?

Comment: @MajidAli I added my xml, could you check that?

Comment: I haven't found root cause and solution for this issue, just know it cause by the `VideoView`. I just want to simplify by using built-in component but it's seem complicated. So I go back to the solution using ExoPlayer, replace `VideoView` by `PlayerView, and the problem solved. Close this topic. Thanks!